# image are not showing on imageview. in ios

Tags: ios, iphone

http://hauwengweb.azurewebsites.net/api/AccomodationImages/images/1

I'm trying to download image on `imageView`. If you will paste this url on browser it will show, but on `imageView` it's not showing. If you will try any other image, then the same code will work, but when I used this url, the image does not show.

Comment: Please post your code, how are you using URL...

Comment: the URL contains irregular image ,

Comment: I thing u missed the full URL or missed the extension

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik URLs don’t need file extensions, you know… That being said, the image in question seems to be a WebP image, which is not a format supported by `UIImage`.

Comment: [cell.imgAccomadation setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"

http://hauwengweb.azurewebsites.net/api/AccomodationImages/images/1"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"user"]];   that's code i m Using

Comment: You are using either SDWebimage or AFNetworkings own UIimage catagory but that wont help as the URL is non absolute

Answer (score 3):

The image in question seems to be a WebP image (served with the wrong MIME type of `image/png`), which is not a format natively supported by `UIImage`. However, you can use [iOS-WebP](https://github.com/seanooi/iOS-WebP) to decode the image:

Add the framework, header and implementation to your project, then use:

```
#import "UIImage+WebP.h"

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://hauwengweb.azurewebsites.net/api/AccomodationImages/images/1"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithWebPData:data];
```

And please remember to do the download and decoding steps asynchronously so as not to block the main UI.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik That’s generally what the `Content-Type` header is for. The client can even send `Accept: image/png` in the request headers and the server can then send the PNG representation of the image instead of the WebP representation for clients not supporting that (just remember to send `Vary: Accept` as well).

Comment: ^ I was replying to a now-deleted comment.

Comment: but its showing data in NSData then why self.img.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data]; this line is not working? and also image is showing in browser.  What is the exact reason for that ?its bcz of  wrong image URL ?

Comment: That’s what I would expect. The data could be loaded that’s why `data != nil` (so it has nothing to do with the URL) but turning it into a `UIImage` fails because the data is not understood by UIKit, so `self.img.image` is `nil`.

Comment: The Image probably shows in your browsers because you’re using Chrome which supports WebP [natively](http://caniuse.com/webp) (it’s Google’s invention). Try any other browser and it won’t work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://hauwengweb.azurewebsites.net/api/AccomodationImages/images/1"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
self.img.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

## Edit

The URL you provided is not an absolute path hence the data being fetched cannot be converted into an UIImage. There is something wrong with the URL or the formatting of it.

Comment: r u checked the URL Is valid or not , I think it is the irregular URL means the URL not completed fully

Comment: Yes probably lemme recheck it once again

Comment: There is data coming from URL but the `UIImage` object is nil.. strange.
Broken URL might be the problem

Comment: ya URL is wrong if you have a doubt check in browser

Comment: the url is same in the browser, but its not the absolute url i guess

Comment: @SahebRoy but its showing data in NSData then why self.img.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data]; this line is not working? and also image is showing in browser.

Comment: There will be data but when you convert that data to `UIimage` it is nil, meaning that data isnt the image's one.